# Getting rid of mounted sd card notification on ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, notification, sd-card, m10

Every time I switch on the M10 phablet I got a notification that tells me there is an SD card inserted.

OK , I already know that. Is there any way to prevent that notification to be triggered ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into the *System Settings* app, and the *Notification* page therein, you can disable notifications for the *External Drives* app. That should disable the notification.